# VB - displaying chart from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, charts, datagrid, linechart

I am willing to show a Line chart that is based from datagridview, but I would like to be able to show not only all the x values, but showing only each 5 or 10 values, for example I had record of temperature in my room every hour in 10 days, so I got 24x10 = 240 data, but I would like to be able to show only the value in each every 3 hour showed on the chart. another ex. I have data from 1-100 I want to show chart only from each data 5,10,15,20,... how is it possibly done ?

```
   Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    For Count As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Item(0, Count).Value, dataGridView1.Item(2, Count).Value)
    Next
```

the code above has successfully showed the normal line chart.

Comment: Why are you storing your information in the DataGridView? It is named DataGrid*View* for a reason :) Do you have a backing data source or array with the data?

Comment: actually the datagrid imports data from excel file, i need to view and analyze the data using vb (w/o ms excel) for some reason ^^

Answer (score 0):

Skip the points you don't want to plot in the loop using [Mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in vb.net

```
Dim divisor = 3
Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
Chart1.Series(0).Points.Clear()
For count As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If (DataGridView1.Item(0, count).Value Mod divisor = 0) Then
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DataGridView1.Item(0, count).Value, DataGridView1.Item(2, count).Value)
    End If
Next count
```

This skips all x values into which 3 does not divide without a remainder. You can change `Dim divisor = 3` to `Dim divisor = 5` to skip all x values into which 5 does not divide without a remainder, etc.

Comment: thank you so much for the clear answer and solution :) @Verdolino